# authorization keys with gateway machine

Tags: ssh

I am trying to set up authorization keys so that I can log in to a remote machine without a password.

The complication is, I have to go through a university gateway machine (machine1) first before I can get to the remote machine (machine2).

I have created authorization keys on my local machine and have added the public key to the list of authorized keys on machine1. This is fine; I can now ssh into machine1 without a password.

I'm not clear on the next step. Do I now:

(a) need to generate more keys on machine1 and add them to the authorized_keys on machine2? or (b) put the same public key (from my local machine) that I just added to machine1, to machine2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do both, basically.

### a) more keys

You could go ahead and create keys on `machine1` and copy the public key to `machine2`'s `/home/yourusername/.ssh/authorized_keys` file.

If you don't decide for the alternative below, I'd suggest this method. If someone gains your private key for `machine2` on `machine1`, he still does not have your private key on your client for `machine1`.

### b) same key

You could also take the public key which you copied to `machine1` and put it on `machine2`. In this case, you must also copy your private key to `machine1` to successfully ssh from `machine1` to `machine2`.

I would not recommend that, because your single, only private key is now available on a remote system.

### Alternative

#### c) ProxyCommand

Keep the private key privately on your client. Only copy the public key to each machine's `/home/yourusername/.ssh/authorized_keys`. On your client, set up `/home/yourusername/.ssh/config` (assuming you use Linux on your client):

```
Host machine1
    HostName machine1.domain.tld
    Port 22   # or whichever port that is in your scenario
    User yourusername
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/machine1privatekey

Host machine2
    HostName hostname   # resolves in the local network? If not, give its IP address here
    Port 22
    User yourusername
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/machine1privatekey # the same as above
    ProxyCommand ssh -W machine2:22 machine1
```

In that case, a simple `ssh machine2` will connect you to machine2 via machine1 without the need to first ssh to machine1 and then manually ssh to machine2.

Additional advantage: your private key only needs to sit on your client and not on a remote system.

Edit:

#### d) SSH agent forwarding

You could, probably, keep both private keys for `machine1` and `machine2` on your client and use ssh agent forwarding to make `machine1` forward your private key from the client to `machine2`. This is considered [risky](https://heipei.github.io/2015/02/26/SSH-Agent-Forwarding-considered-harmful/), and I am not using it, but it should be something along those lines:

```
$ ssh-agent /bin/bash
$ ssh-add ~/.ssh/machine*privatekey
$ ssh -A -p 22 yourusername@machine1.domain.tld 'ssh -p 22 yourusernameqmachine2'
```